# Block certain domains in ECS cluster tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

[UPDATED] I am using a 3rd party vendor for some resource for the application and I'm trying to test how the application behaves when the 3rd party goes down. My application is hosted on AWS ECS, and I am trying to block the domains of 3rd party so that my application can't reach the 3rd party.

Ques - How to block the domains in AWS ECS?

---

[OLD] I am trying to block certain domains in our ECS cluster tasks. I have added the hosts under extra_hosts in docker-compose.yml.
Ex:
service:
extra_hosts:
- ":127:0:0:1"
But, this domain has not been blocked in the AWS ECS cluster task.

How to block certain domains in AWS ECS cluster tasks?

Comment: As you can see here https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-compose-features/ the `extra_hosts` setting in docker-compose does not map to anything in ECS. Can you describe in more detail what exactly you are trying to do? You want to block outbound network requests from your ECS tasks to certain external domains?

Comment: Your update is even less detailed than the original question. Again I ask: Can you describe **in more detail** what **exactly** you are trying to do?

Comment: Are you deploying to Fargate or EC2? And if EC2, which networking mode are you using?

Comment: I believe you would have to use a network firewall https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/network-firewall-configure-domain-rules

Comment: @MarkB Thank you for the reference link, I will follow this.

Comment: We are deploying to Fargate.